# Overlay a tile layer on top of another tile layer using leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, geoserver

I aim to overlay a tile layer on top of another. The first tile layer is created using L.tileLayer() using the url: baseUrl='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' and the second tile layer is created using a wms service (L.tileLayer.wms) hosted on geoserver which is serving some .tif images as tiles. I want to create something like: https://alpha.anthropo.co/znz-demo

As can be seen in the demo, once the user zooms out one can see the base map and after a specific zoom level, the .tif images can also be seen on top of the base map.

In my implementation, I can only see either one tile layer or another. And after a certain zoom level, I can see the geoserver tile layer but cannot see the osm layer at all and I suppose that it might be because the osm tilelayer might not be supporting zoom levels that high and hence I am only seeing the geoserver tile layer.

I have tried creating/setting pane levels, making the served tiles transparent using geoserver, layer groups, setting transparent param to true and format param to 'image/png' at the same time when creating the tilelayer, and using the layer.bringToFront() method but none of these seem to help in this case or maybe they do but because I am a newbie to leaflet/web mapping world I am not using them the right way.

[geoserver footprint behaviour and merge behaviour configuration screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDDm7.png)

It would be great if you can help me with this :) Thanks...!

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Title -->
        <title> Sample: Loading tiles from Geoserver </title>

        <!-- Including Leaflet CSS file in the head section of the document. -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./leaflet_js/leaflet.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />

        <!-- Including Leaflet JavaScript file after Leaflet's CSS file. -->
        <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
        <script src="./leaflet_js/leaflet.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
    
        <script>
            // Latitude and Longitude of the point that is displayed when the map first loads.
            var startPoint = [latitude=-5.733, longitude=39.298]

            // Creating map options
            var mapOptions = {
                center: startPoint,
                zoom: 15,
                crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,            
            };
            
            // Creating a map object
            var map = L.map('map', mapOptions);

            var tanzania_layer = L.tileLayer.wms(
                baseUrl='http://localhost:8080/geoserver/OpenAI_Tanzania/wms?', {
                    layers: 'train',
                    maxZoom: 25,
                    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
                    noWrap: true,
                    tranparent: true,
                    format: 'image/png'
                });

            var osm_layer = L.tileLayer(
                baseUrl='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    maxZoom: 25,
                    attribution: '© OpenStreetMap',
                    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
                    noWrap: true,
                    tranparent: true,
                    format: 'image/png'
                });

            baseLayer = L.layerGroup([tanzania_layer, osm_layer]);
            map.addLayer(baseLayer);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0enJq.png)

I have taken care of the crs and if I only show the geoserver tile layer then I can see the data here so the layers align as well.

I would like to see the geoserver tile layer data on top of the current osm layer that is shown in the output screenshot.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Is the background of your tanzania tiles transparent? The tiles from tile.openstreetmap.org don't contain a transparent background. So they can only be used as the lowest layer and not on top of something else.

Comment: aah I see okay, I don't know if the background of the tanzania tiles are transparent but I can check for sure, if you know of a way how to do it that would be great. Also, the tanzania tiles are only available for a tiny area in the world so it does not contain data for other parts of the world as one would expect. Does the tiles being transparent still make a difference? Thanks...!

Comment: Well, you are trying to put one image on top of another image. So the top image needs to include transparency or you won't see the bottom image. How to check that? Open the image in a graphics program.